# Indian B1 B2 visa crossing the border at San Diego

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork

I entered USA on March 20 through air with my Indian passport and B1 B2 visa.
I am returning to India on June 6th from Boston.

Towards the end of May I intend to go to San Diego on a weekend and enter Tijuana for two days before flying back to Boston.
Will I have any problem during my reentry at the USA-Mexico border?

Comment: Maybe a good idea to have confirmation of your return flight to India from Boston with you when you renter the US

Comment: It's very unlikely that you would have a problem. Just don't bring back any illegal drugs or immigrants.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I have any Problem?

No one knows; it's up to the border officer whether they find you suspicious or not, but as for formalities, as long as your visa is valid you're fine.

Comment: Under [automatic revalidation](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date/auto-revalidate.html), it's not even necessary for the visa to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how long your visa is and if it is valid, you shouldn't have any issues. The visa should also be multiple entry.

Comment: The multiple entry point is a good one.  I don't think the US issues many limited-entry B-1/B-2 visas, but anyone planning to use a visa to enter the US a second time should definitely check the "Entries" entry to ensure that it either reads "M" or has a sufficiently high number.